# Binomial expansion to find a specific term (coefficient)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

[image]

for this question I tried to use binomial theorem to find a specific term. However, I eventually cannot find a valid value of n and r and p. My working is shown in the picture and please tell me my mistake.

Comment: Have a look at the multinomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

To find the coefficient of $x^3y^5$ in $(1+xy+y^2)^n$,

We will need to choose to multiply $1$ "$y^2$", $3$ "$xy$"s and $n−4$ "$1$"s from:

$\overbrace{(1+xy+y^2)(1+xy+y^2)(1+xy+y^2) \dots (1+xy+y^2)}^{n}$

For example, $(1+xy+\boldsymbol{y^2})(1+\boldsymbol{xy}+y^2)(1+\boldsymbol{xy}+y^2)(1+\boldsymbol{xy}+y^2) \dots (\boldsymbol{1}+xy+y^2)$, multiplying the bold terms will give us one way to get $x^3y^5$

So the coefficient of $x^3y^5$ = $\binom{n}{1,3,n-4} = \frac{n!}{1!3!(n-4)!}$

Comment: Thanks for listening to my comment. +1

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(x^{r-p})(y^{r-p})(y^{2r})$$ is wrong.

It should be
$$\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(xy)^{r-p}(y^2)^{p}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(x^{r-p})(y^{r+p})$$

Comment: You can always verify your answer using a combinatorial argument. The coefficient should be the same as arranging $1$ "$y^2$", $3$ "$xy$"s and $n-4$ "$1$"s in a row.

Comment: @Nicholas  Beautiful.  Please post that as an answer for the benefit of he community,

Answer (score 0):

Notice, in the last factor, the power of $y$ should be $2p$ not $2r$

The general term should be as follows $$\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(xy)^{r-p}(y^2)^{p}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(x)^{r-p}(y)^{r-p}(y^{2p})=\binom{n}{r}\binom{r}{p}(x)^{r-p}(y)^{r+p}$$
now, comparing the corresponding powers with that of $x^3y^5$, you should have $r-p=3\tag 1$

$r+p=5\tag 2$